# The garbage collector warning since SQLAdmin AuthenticationBackend enabled

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I'm pretty sure my issue is related to my code and Python skills, however, I'm struggling to find the correct way. I hope that the community here can help me.

```
The garbage collector is trying to clean up non-checked-in connection <AdaptedConnection <Connection(Thread-3, started daemon 15844)>>, which will be dropped, as it cannot be safely terminated.  Please ensure that SQLAlchemy pooled connections are returned to the pool explicitly, either by calling ``close()`` or by using appropriate context managers to manage their lifecycle.
C:\mSpaceLock\mSpaceLock-www\env\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py:176: SAWarning: The garbage collector is trying to clean up non-checked-in connection <AdaptedConnection <Connection(Thread-3, started daemon 15844)>>, which will be dropped, as it cannot be safely terminated.  Please ensure that SQLAlchemy pooled connections are returned to the pool explicitly, either by calling ``close()`` or by using appropriate context managers to manage their lifecycle.
```

This is part of FastAPI application and AuthenticationBackend class is part of SQLAdmin extension

my `authenticate_user` function requires `session`:

```py
async def authenticate_user(
    username: str,
    password: str,
    session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session),
):
    user = await get_user(username=username, session=session)
    # print(user)
    if not user:
        return False
    if not Hasher.verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):
        return False
    return user
```

normally in FastAPI endpoint, I do the following method and it doesn't cause any Garbage collector warning.

```py
@router.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
    response: Response,
    form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
    session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session),
):
    user = await authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password, session)
```

However in SQLAdmin `login` function has take request as an instance variable, so I need to call take session within the function, which only way I found it would work is the following:

```py
class AdminAuth(AuthenticationBackend):
    async def login(
        self,
        request: Request,
    ) -> bool:
        form = await request.form()
        username, password = form["username"], form["password"]
        print("username is", username)
        print("password is", password)
        user = await authenticate_user(
            username, password, session=async_session_maker()
        )
        if not user:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Incorrect username or password",
            )
        if not user.superuser:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="You are not permitted!!!",
            )
        admin_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
        admin_token = create_access_token(
            data={"sub": user.email}, expires_delta=admin_token_expires
        )
        print("access token is ", admin_token)
        request.session.update({"admin_token": admin_token})
        return True
```

And this is how I get session:

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite+aiosqlite:///./sql_app.sqlite"
engine = create_async_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)

async_session_maker = async_sessionmaker(
    engine,
    expire_on_commit=False,
)


async def get_async_session() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async with async_session_maker() as session:
        try:
            yield session
        finally:
            await session.close()
```

I've added the `finally: await session close()` as the solution to that, but it doesn't solve my garbage collector warning. Can you suggest me something?